# Run curl commands after docker server (kong) starts

Tags: docker, kong

I have a docker container that internally starts a server. (I don't own this. I am just reusing it)

Once the server starts, I am running some curl commands that hit this server.
I am running the above steps in a script. Here's the issue:
the docker container starts but internally I think it is taking some time to actually start the server in it.

Before that server is up and running, it looks like the curl commands start executing and give an error that server could not be found. If I manually run this a few seconds later, it works fine though.

Please let me know if there is a way to solve this. I don't think using entry point or CMD will work for similar reasons.
Also, if that matters, the server I am using is kong.

thanks, Om.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to this is to perform some sort of health check; once you've verified that the server is healthy you can start making live requests to it.  As you've noticed, the container existing or the server process running on its own isn't enough to guarantee that the container can handle requests.

A typical approach to this is to make some request to the server that will fail until the server is ready.  You don't need to modify the container to do this.  In some environments like Kubernetes, you can specify health checks or probes as part of the deployment configuration, but for a simple shell script, you can just run `curl` in a loop:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d ...
RUNNING=false
for i in $(seq 30); do
  # Try GET / and see if it succeeds
  if curl -s http://localhost:8080/
  then
    echo Server is running
    RUNNING=true
    break
  else
    echo Server not running, waiting
    sleep 1
  fi
done
if [ "$RUNNING" = false ]; then
  echo Server did not start within 30s
  # docker stop ... && docker rm ...
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the port is up, this simple script is very handy:

https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it